# JAX WS ClassCasting Error

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

This is our ServiceRequest.java

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "ServiceRequest",
         namespace = "http://ejb.service.blue2.bcbsa.com",
         propOrder = {"any"})
public class ServiceRequest implements Serializable {
  @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
  protected Object any;

  public Object getAny() {
    return any;
  }

  public void setAny(Object value) {
    this.any = value;
  }
}
```

in my Implementation file i mentioned like this

```
IBMSOAPElement requestElement = (IBMSOAPElement)serviceRequest.getAny();
```

in this line its showing

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xerces.dom.ElementNSImpl incompatible with com.ibm.websphere.webservices.soap.IBMSOAPElement
```

Answer (score 0):

Its going to be difficult to answer the question without looking at the code (dependencies), WebSphere and the feature packs you have installed. I would look at the compile time dependencies you have on JaxB (Jax-WS) and make sure they are provided by the version of WebSphere you are using.

Answer (score 0):

```
Element eobj = (Element)serviceRequest.getAny();

IBMSOAPElement requestElement = (IBMSOAPElement)new SODHealper().convertDataObjectToSOAPElement(eobj);
```

now its works fine!!!!!

Comment: You really should avoid using specif-vendor implementations. This code just works for Websphere Application Server, not for JBoss (WildFly) or any other.